# Calculate covariance matrix from x,y,z data

Tags: localization, ros, odometry

In **ROS** I've recorded a bag file from a custom robot (in real world) that does not provide covariance matrix and I want to use `/odom` to feed an **EKF**, but covariance matrix is 0. How can I calculate it?

**Note**:
Covariance matrix is needed by EKF to estimate position.

It's a sample of `/odom`:

```
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.082
      y: 0.507
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.789272088731
      w: 0.614043622188
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.104
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0663225115758
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *can't* estimate the covariance from the state.  You need the equations used to *find* the state.

This is because the covariance (along with the markov assumption) represents *how* the robot got to the state.   A robot at location (10,5,1) does not always have the same covariance matrix, right? You need to know what actions brought it to that state.

Barring any ros-based solution (are you sure the SLAM / EKF nodes can't do this for you?) you'll have to do this:

1. Find the kinematics model for the robot (differential drive, ackerman, whatever)
2. Read in the odometery and control command, and use the kinematics equations and control inputs as the *u* and *f()* for the EKF (using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter#Discrete-time_predict_and_update_equations)) as a reference.
3. Find the Jacobian of the kinematics equations with respect to each state element
4. Feed the Jacobian and control / odometery into the EKF as the *F* term (using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter#Discrete-time_predict_and_update_equations)) as a reference.

In case you are wondering, yes this effectively reproduces the work done by the /odom node, since the output of the kinematics equations is precisely what /odom reports.