# Caculate/Specify the covariance matrix for a omniwheel robot

Tags: ros, slam, odometry, errors, matrix

I have an omnidirectional robot (x, y and rotation around z), which I would like to use the SLAM-algorithm from ROS. But the odometry from the robot has a drift, which makes some error. To improve the odometry error I need to calculate or specify the covariance matrix. How do I do that on a real system?

Regards
Markus

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from first principals there's a pretty thorough paper [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Emotionplanning/papers/sbp_papers/kalman/chong_accurate_odometry_error.pdf)

There's a question here which is related [Calculate covariance matrix from x,y,z data](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/calculate-covariance-matrix-from-x-y-z-data)

And there's some pretty practical advice here: https://answers.ros.org/question/12642/calculating-covariances-of-robots-odometry/